# SQL Fiddle cannot create Foreign Key

Tags: mysql, sql, ddl

I'm trying to build the following in SQL fiddle and cannot for the life of me see why it will not work, it may just be late but can anyone offer pointers on this one please.

```
CREATE TABLE Trainers (
   Trainer_ID INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   Firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
   Lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
   Email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   DOB DATE
);

CREATE TABLE Captured
(
  Caught_ID INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  Trainer_ID INT(6),
  Caught  TIMESTAMP,
  FOREIGN KEY (Trainer_ID) REFERENCES Trainers(Trainer_ID)
);
```

Comment: What's your dbms? What's your error message?

Comment: MySql 5.7 'cannot assign foreign key'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your FK is `SIGNED` and thus is a different type than `Trainer`'s PK, an `UNSIGNED` `INT(6)`; change `Captured.Trainer_ID` to `INT(6) UNSIGNED`